# Prove that for m > 0, the following identity holds: $\sum_{k=0}^m (-1)^{m-k}{n+k-1\choose k}{n\choose m-k} = 0$

Tags: combinatorics

How shall I tackle this proof?  I would brute force it because my knowledge is minimal.  Can this one be done combinatorially?  How to proceed with the alternating sign has stumped me as well.

Comment: Personally I would use generating functions, since that's my go to for everything, especially things that involve some sort of convolution. Computers can also provide proofs of such things, as for whether there is a combinatorial proof, most likely - the way to deal with an alternating sign is often to split the sum up into k odd and k even.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[#ffd,10px]{\ds{%
\sum_{k = 0}^{m}\pars{-1}^{m - k}{n + k - 1 \choose k}{n \choose m - k}}}
=
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{m - k}\
\overbrace{\bracks{{-n \choose k}\pars{-1}^{k}}}
^{\begin{array}{l}
\mbox{Negating}
\\
\mbox{the Binomial}
\end{array}}\
{n \choose m - k}
\\[5mm] = &\
\pars{-1}^{m}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}
{-n \choose k}\bracks{z^{m - k}}\pars{1 + z}^{n} =
\pars{-1}^{m}\bracks{z^{m}}\pars{1 + z}^{n}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}
{-n \choose k}z^{k}
\\[5mm] = &\
\pars{-1}^{m}\bracks{z^{m}}\pars{1 + z}^{n}\pars{1 + z}^{-n} =
\pars{-1}^{m}\bracks{z^{m}}z^{0} = \bbx{\delta_{m0}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Start by manipulating the summand
\begin{eqnarray*}
\binom{n+k-1}{k} \binom{n}{m-k}= \frac{n}{m} \binom{m}{k} \binom{n-k-1}{m-1}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now express the second binomial coefficient as the coefficient of the a function
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \binom{n-k-1}{m-1} = [x^{m-1}]: (1+x)^{n-k-1}
\end{eqnarray*}
So
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=0}^{m} (-1)^{m-k} \binom{m}{k} \binom{n-k-1}{m-1} &=& \frac{(-1)^{m}n}{m} \sum_{k=0}^{m} (-1)^{k}\binom{m}{k} \binom{n-k-1}{m-1} \\
&=& \frac{(-1)^{m}n}{m} [x^{m-1}]: \sum_{k=0}^{m} (-1)^{k}\binom{m}{k} (1+x)^{n-k-1} \\
&=& \frac{(-1)^{m}n}{m} [x^{m-1}]: (1+x)^{n-1} \left( 1- \frac{1}{1+x} \right)^m \\
&=& \frac{(-1)^{m}n}{m} [x^{m-1}]: (1+x)^{n-m-1} x^m =\color{red}{0}. \\
\end{eqnarray*}